# How to let clojure to generate this simple YAML file?

Tags: clojure, ansible, yaml

I want clojure to generate this simple ansible YAML file:

```
- hosts: 172.16.10.104 
  tasks: 
    - name: ping
      ping:
```

I use the https://github.com/owainlewis/yaml to generate it:

```
 (def data [{:hosts "172.16.10.104"}
         {:tasks [{
                   :name "ping",
                   :ping ""
                   }]}
         ])
```

and got this:

```
- hosts: 172.16.10.104
- tasks:
    - name: ping
      ping: ''
```

I want the "tasks" not the "- tasks", how to fix it?

Comment: I am sorry for do not know that...I will do it now for all my ask...sorry again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you structure your data as follows,

```
(def data [{:host  "172.16.10.104"
            :tasks [{:name "ping" :ping ""}]}])
```

then

```
(yaml/generate-string data :dumper-options {:flow-style :block})
```

yields

```
"- host: 172.16.10.104\n  tasks:\n  - name: ping\n    ping: ''\n"
```

which formatted, is:

```
- host: 172.16.10.104
  tasks:
  - name: ping
    ping: ''
```